# The values extracted from an xml document are not separated by spaces

Tags: xml, xpath, text-mining, rapidminer

I am using Read XML in Rapidminer to read a file and extract some nodes.

My problem is that whenever a node appears more than once in the XML file, Rapidminer extracts all the node values and builds a string without spaces between the values.
Instead I would like a comma separated string.

So for the XPath attribute:

```
//nounPhrase/node()
```

And the XML code:

```
<extractedData>
<nounPhrase occurrence="1" origin="syllabs">homme blanc</nounPhrase>
<nounPhrase occurrence="1" origin="syllabs">peine</nounPhrase>
<nounPhrase occurrence="2" origin="syllabs">religieuse</nounPhrase>
<nounPhrase occurrence="1" origin="syllabs">peur</nounPhrase>
</extractedData>
```

Rapidminer extracts this string:

```
homme blancpeinereligieusepeur
```

While what I wanted is:

```
homme blanc, peine, religeuse, peur
```

Does anyone know what to do? I do not see any option in Read XML controlling this aspect of the extraction.

Configuration I am using for Read XML:

xpath for examination: /

xpath for attributes: several, among which //nounPhrase/node()

Answer (score 0):

If RapidMinor supports XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(//nounPhrase, ', ')
```

If RapidMinor supports only XPath 1.0, and you have only 4 `nounPhrases`:

```
concat(//nounPhrase[1], ', ', //nounPhrase[2], ', ', //nounPhrase[3], ', ', //nounPhrase[4])
```

If RapidMinor supports only XPath 1.0, and you have varying numbers of `nounPhrases`, string joining has to be done outside of XPath.

Comment: Thank you. None of the two solutions works on Rapidminer 5.3. Anyway I was just trying this software... for the moment I'll stick to R where I manage to work better. I'll keep the question open if it may come of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Generate Extract operator with the concat Xpath example given earlier. You would need to read the complete XML first without any parsing so this might not suit your particular requirement.